# DAL methods with lots of parameters

Tags: c#, methods, parameters

I have several methods in my DAL, with quite a few parameters:

```
public Collection<Proforma> SearchAllProforma(DateTime? startDate = null, DateTime? endDate = null,
        int? institutionID = null, int? inspectionID = null, bool? isFollowup = null, bool? excludeDeleted = null,
        bool? nutritionalOnly = null, int? parentInspectionID = null)
```

Should I condense these down to take an object parameter? Or leave them the way they are, using optional parameters? Or both?

Edit - I should really have said, that each one of these parameters maps to a parameter for a stored procedure.

Comment: What problem are you trying to solve here?

Comment: If anything, consider using Entity Framework instead.

Comment: If you're using a recent version of C# you can use named parameters.

Comment: I asked a similar question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7256009/refactoring-large-constructors

Comment: I am not using Entity framework, because at the moment some of our SQL servers still use 2000. Some of the tables have been around for a few years as well and they aren't particularly well designed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you to Create a class for all those parameter as properties.

And then send the class as parameter.

```
Class SerachAllProformaParameter
{
//All Properties.
}

SerachAllProformaParameter parameter= new SerachAllProformaParameter();
parameter.PropertyName="value";

public Collection<RoIVProforma> SearchAllProforma(parameter);
```

Comment: I think that I am going to try this approach out, alongside my existing approach, and see which I prefer. I am not sure that I like the syntax for calling the methods though. Seems clunky (especially in VB.NET).

Comment: And also, I have a lot of methods with many parameters, so implementing loads of classes for each of these might be a lot of work.

Answer (score 1):

> Should I condense these down to take an object parameter?

Not necessarily. The default values seem okay (I assume your function can handle `null` parameters without issue). If you're using a recent version of C# you can call this function like:

```
SearchAllProforma(institutionID: 33);
```

Which isn't all that bad, in my opinion.

Comment: That is precisely the way that I call the methods.

Answer (score 0):

Consider that a lot of them have their default values, for *usability* perspctive I would add several **overrides** of this method with different quantity of parameters.

In this way, for a consumer of your method would be **easier** to choose appropriate one without having in front of eyes **all that parameters** in intellisense window.

```
public Collection<RoIVProforma> SearchAllProforma(DateTime? startDate = null) 
{
   ...
}

public Collection<RoIVProforma> SearchAllProforma(DateTime? startDate = null, DateTime? endDate = null)
{
 ...
}

public Collection<RoIVProforma> SearchAllProforma(DateTime? startDate = null, DateTime? endDate = null,
        int? institutionID = null)
{
 ...
}

...
```

Comment: I don't see the advantage in adding multiple overloads for a method that already has every parameter as optional. Just seems like extra noise and stuff that I have to maintain to me.

Comment: @ScottD: as I wrote, the benefit is when you write "." in intellisense you see not all that parameters, but like a first option would see the method with no parameters, and after can use "<" and ">" to go for other definitions.

Answer (score 0):

> Should I condense these down to take an object parameter?

Yes, absolutely. Looking at this method signature makes my eyes start bleeding.

Comment: That was a mild example as well.

Comment: You mean you have more parameters than that?

Comment: I have methods with more parameters than that.

Answer (score 0):

Personally, the best way here is to pass an `Expression<Func<RoIVProforma, bool>>` instance into SearchAllProforma method. But it is more hard to implement parsing expression, if your DAL doesn't use any LINQ-based underlying data source.
The same time, a method with many optional parameters is the worst.

Answer (score 0):

**Use object as parameter**, it is a good approach..

Answer (score 0):

You can pass a predicate lambda expression to the method if all the arguments belong to some entity of yours.

I use following method to search for some criteria among my entities.

```
public List<Personel> GetAll(Func<Personel, bool> predicate = null)
        {
            List<Personel> result = new List<Personel>();

            if (predicate == null)
            {
                result = personelRepo.Table.ToList();
            }
            else
            {
                foreach (var item in personelRepo.Table)
                {
                    if (predicate(item))
                        result.Add(item);
                }
            }

            return result;
        }
```

and then pass a predicate to the method when calling like:

```
var myFilteredEntities = GetAll(e => e.Name == "John" && e.IsMarried == false);
```